# MonoDevelop and XCode

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm using MonoDevelop 2.8.5 and XCode 4.2.1.
Every time I'm switching to monodevelop window from anything else, it starts to update XCode project file and pops XCode window.
More over, when I switch from XCode back to monotouch, it updates the project and switches back to XCode.
Thats's really annoying. How do I disable this "feature"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was fixed by downloading new Monodevelop: 2.8.6 beta

Answer (score 0):

This behavior cannot be disabled, since there is no other way that MonoDevelop can use to communicate with xcode 4. This is because MonoDevelop creates an Xcode project on the fly (when you dbl clic any xib file within MD) and then MD launches xcode with the generated xcode project.

when you do all necessary changes in xcode and you switch back to MD the OnFocus event of MD (i don't really know if thats the event's name btw) process the changes you have done on the xcode project and modifies it in order to maintain both projects (xcode and MD) on sync

My suggestion is just make all necessary changes on xcode save them and then close it, then work on MD as usual and if you need to reopen xcode again work on it, Xcode won't bother you as long as you don't focus the MD window

I hope this helps.

Alex

Comment: it used to work this way couple of days before. XCode pops up every time I made a changes to the source file and hit Cmd-S. MS saves source file and opens up XCode.